# Why QFontMetrics return rect with cropped width in Windows 7?

Tags: qt, windows-7, qpainter, qmenubar

I paint some text in subclassed menubar. And `QFontMetrics` return rectangle with cropped width. This happens in Windows 7. But it works as I expect in Debian with KDE. Why is it happen and how can I fix it?

[image]

```
class MainMenuBar : public QMenuBar
{
public:
    explicit MainMenuBar(QWidget *parent = 0);

protected:
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);

private:
    QFont _font;
};

MainMenuBar::MainMenuBar(QWidget *parent) : QMenuBar(parent)
{
    _font = font();
}

void MainMenuBar::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QMenuBar::paintEvent(event);

    QPainter painter(this);

    painter.setFont(_font);

    QRect rect = geometry();
    rect.setRight(200);
    rect.setLeft(rect.right() - QFontMetrics(_font).width("WWW")); // Cuts
    //rect.setLeft(rect.right() - QFontMetrics(font()).width("WWW")); // Doesn't cut
    painter.drawText(rect, Qt::AlignVCenter, "WWW");
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    setMenuBar(new MainMenuBar(this));
    menuBar()->addAction(".");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a similar situation I would not restrict the text like that. Just allocate the rectangle as long as possible (better) or maybe to fit 4 W (not as good).

```
painter.drawText(rect, Qt::AlignVCenter | Qt::AlignRight, "WWW");
```

And `Qt::AlignRight` will do the trick. No idea why the rendering is slightly different, though. If you clarify on your task then we will be able to come up with better approach.

***The best practice*** would be not even that but QVBoxLayout for the entire window and QHBoxLayout for the upper widget with 'stretch' (here unsure whether you just want to right-align the text or make a fixed-width left stretch before it?) on the left plus QLabel added as widget (maybe with the right alignment). But you don't ask that and I can only assume that you did not try the better layout approach.